# サイトのオートリロードはサーバーにどれくらい負荷がかかるか

Tags: javascript, java-ee

JavaEEで制作したサイトにて、１０分に１度の頻度で、JavaScriptでメイン画面をオートリロードしようと考えています。
その場合、F5アタックのように、サーバーに負荷がかかるのではと思います。herokuを使用しています。
負荷を軽減、回避する方法があれば教えてください。

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = '/メイン画面';
    }, 600 * 1000);
</script>
```

補足

[JavaEEのサイト](https://miyamarchere.herokuapp.com)では、heroku schedulerで、２つのテーブルを商品情報が移動します。移動するタイミングは商品のリアルタイムの販売終了時間によるので、それを正しく表示させるために、１０分おきにメイン画面の再読み込みが必要と考えております。現時点ではデモとして、１０分おきに１つずつテーブルを移動させ、全部移動し終わったら元のテーブルに戻るという設定にしています。

Answer (score 0):

サーバー側も質問者さんの守備範囲のようですが、であればサーバー側でのキャッシュを検討してはいかがですか？

例えば DB のデータをクライアントに提供しているとかなら、DB のデータをキャッシュしておき、DB のデータが更新されたら新しいデータでキャッシュを書き直すとか。

「JavaEEで制作したサイト」でどのようにできるか分かりませんのでハズレでしたらすみません。

Comment: サーバーは初心者のため守備範囲ではありませんが、不具合が必要になれば、heroku pgBouncerを導入してみようと思います。

Comment: @kieton ここでの守備範囲とは kieton さんが使いこなしているかどうかではなく、「自分自身 (もしくは所属する組織等)で管理しているサーバー」か、「第三者のサーバーに対して」なのかを指しているのだと思います。

Comment: 守備範囲というのは cubick さんが言われる通りです。

Comment: heroku pgBouncer というのは DB の接続プールだそうですが、今回の質問のような話がなくても、最初から必要なものだと思いますけど。

Comment: 守備範囲の意味を教えていただきありがとうございます。herokuも全くの手探りのため、pgBouncerも必死に探して見つけた答えでした。キャッシュについてアドバイスありがとうございます。これから勉強していきたいと思います。